# How to do the css template layout?

Tags: html, css

#### I want is to have something like this effect.

[image]

I tried to make a css template by following the picture above, but I don't know how to do it?

Do you can make css effect according to the above picture?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a programming service. Please tell us what you have tried so far, and what your issue is.

Comment: Are you asking how to draw diagonal lines with CSS? CSS is a poor tool for that job. Use SVG for vector art.

Comment: @Quentin Not svg.It is draw diagonal lines with CSS!

Comment: @wentian — CSS is the wrong tool. Stop trying to use it for this.

Comment: @Quentin why is it the wrong tool ?

Comment: @Seblor CSS is not a graphic drawing tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 2D Transformation (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp).

```
.line1 {
width: 112px;
height: 47px;
border-bottom: 1px solid red;
-webkit-transform:
    translateY(-20px)
    translateX(5px)
    rotate(27deg); 
position: absolute; }
```

Here is an example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/giodamelio/htg0Lqd2/1/)

Comment: The problem with this is it's for webkit only browsers which leaves out everything but Safari and Chrome. Even then, neither of those browsers have needed webkit prefixes for this in years! This is an antiquated answer.